# Read only last column from large txt data file with a lot of columns

Tags: python

I'm a novice in Python. 
I'm writing up a jupyter notebook for data analysis which is supposed to work on already provided datafiles.
These datafiles (.txt) contain each a large table of floats, with delimitator '  '. They are ugly in the sense that they have relatively few rows (~2k) and a lot of columns (~100k). 
The "single-file" detailed analysis works fine (I have more than enough RAM to load one of these files entirely in memory, e.g. via np.loadtxt(), and work on it); but I then wanted to attempt a multi-file cross analysis in which I would be only interested in the last column of each file. I cannot find a fast/efficient/nice way of doing this.

What I can do is to np.loadtxt() these files one at a time, then each time copy the last column of the resulting array and delete the rest; and repeat. This is painfully slow but it's working. I was wondering if I could do better!

I also tried this, inspired by something I saw searching the web:

```py
data=[]
for i in range(N_istar):
    for j in range(N_col_pos):
        with open(filename(i,j), 'r') as f:
            lastcol=[]
            line=f.readline()
            while line:
                sp=line.split()
                lastcol.append(sp[-1])
            data.append(lastcol)
```

but this either goes on forever or takes a ridiculous amount of time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use pandas `read_csv(usecols=)`. You *must* know the index or name of the column. Code is clean and short, see below example.

In case you do not know the index of the last column, you can read the first row and count the number of seperators.

**Example**

*test.csv*

```
a  b   c    d
0  1   2    3
2  4   6    8
```

*python code*

```
import pandas as pd

seperator = r"\s*"  # default this will be ",". Using a regex does make it slower.

# column names
pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=seperator, usecols=['d'])

# column index
pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=seperator, header=None, usecols=[3])

# Unknown number of columns
with open('test.csv') as current_file:
    last_column_index = len(current_file.readline().split())
pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=seperator, header=None, usecols=[last_column_index])
```

Comment: Tyvm! This seems to be what I'm looking for! Yet pd.read_csv seems not to be distinguishing between columns (it just reads a long, single column of strings).
Maybe this is relevant: my files are such that the 1st element of each row is in X.XXXXX format, and preceded by three empty spaces; then all others are in exponential format X.XXXXXXE+XXX, and preceded by just two empty spaces. 
Is it possible that pd 'reads' the first 3x' ' group, decides that the delimitator for the whole file must be that, and ignores all subsequent, shorter spacings?
I will experiment a bit. Thanks again!

Comment: see updated answer to use a random number of spaces as delimiter

Comment: @Rocco, `read_csv` uses `,` as default delimiter. This can be changed to another character without loss of performance. In complex cases however, when a regex or multiple characters are needed, the C interpreter can no longer handle this and you will notice a loss of performance.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with the np.readtxt. Usually files are read and processed quickly in python either by using np or pd.
The best trick would be to read each file using pandas/numpy and concatenate the last columns (if you have enough memory). If you ran you, drop the columns you don't use and leave only the last one.

Just to give you the right direction:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6], size=5),
                   'B': np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], size=5)})
print(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6], size=5),
                   'B': np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], size=5)})
print(df2)
conc_df = pd.concat([df1['B'], df2['B']])
print(conc_df.head(10))
```

Comment: Isn't this what Rocco is already doing, but using pandas instead of readline?

Comment: no. read line is very inefficient compared to pandas or numpy, as they are implemented in C and readline invoke the interpreter for every lline. Although the number of lines is not huge, its still should make a different

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` aslo provide `reshape()` method for you.

ex: `f.csv`

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

code

```py
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('f.csv', delimiter=',')
last_col = data[:, -1:].reshape(1,-1)[0]
```

result

```py
>>>last_col.tolist()
[3.0, 6.0, 9.0]
```